# Is there a C#/ASP.Net equivalent to Access' AfterUpdate event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

This sounds ridiculously simple but I can't find anything that will act like Access' AfterUpdate event.  What I want to do is to is this:

[image]

1. User enters a Group Number
2. After Update (tabbing off, clicking into a new field, clicking a button, whatever...), query my table for the Group Name and place it in
   the circle marked "2"
3. Also fill in additional info based on the Group Number

I understand that I can just put in something like a button called "Validation" and then perform #'s 2 and 3, but the users don't want the extra button click.  In Access, this could easily be performed with an AfterUpdate event, so how would I do this with C#?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `TextChanged` event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Beware, you are in a web page, each event will call to the server and will reload the page, a web page is not a local program and the usability is not the same.

Comment: I hate when people complain about button clicks and act like that button click is contributing to wasted time within their day. It's a button click!!! Just click it!!! AAAHHHHHRRRRGGGGG!!!!

Comment: Echoing Gusman and to say you probably want to handle this client-side with JavaScript or use JQuery to take some burden off. You could always delve into Knockout.js etc if you felt brave!

Answer (score 3):

### Server side:

Set `AutoPostBack="True"` for your TextBox and handle `TextChanged` event in your code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="groupTextBox" 
            runat="server" 
            AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnTextChanged="groupTextBox_TextChanged">

</asp:TextBox>
```

### Client Side:

To handle it at client side you can use Javascript like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="groupTextBox2" 
            runat="server" 
            OnBlur="YourJavaScriptMethod();">
</asp:TextBox>
```

and in your method in Javascript could be:

```
function YourJavaScriptMethod()
{
     alert(document.getElementById('<%= groupTextBox2.ClientID %>').value);
}
```

You can send a AJAX request to get data based on the text changed.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, just need to apply it before I can give the checkmark.  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyBones, You are welcome, I would suggest you to approach this via client side code, as `AutoPostBack` will post everything to the server, thus resulting in page reloading itself.